# can't import vue component from npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, vue.js

Good day,

I have recently created an npm package for a navigation-bar which I want to import into my main codebase. I am using vue @components and I can't quite find out how to use the imported component. If anyone knows how to get the npm packaged component into the dom, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a simplified example of what I have tried:

```
npm package 

    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Component from 'vue-class-component';
    import '../navigation-bar.styles.less';
    @Component({template: require('../navigation-bar.html')}})
    export class NavigationBar extends Vue {
       constructor() {
        super();
                  }
    }
    Vue.component('navigation-bar', NavigationBar);

main.ts

    import { NavigationBar } from '@international-client/navigation-bar';
    Vue.component('navigation-bar', NavigationBar);

index.html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Game</title>
        </head>
        <navigation-bar></navigation-bar>
        <body class="game-view">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what is the error? where do you init vue? what element is it attached to?

Comment: There is no error, the navigation bar component displays as <navigation-bar></navigation-bar>.
the navigation-bar.html is below: 
<div class="navigation-bar-container" on-element-blur="onBlur()"
v-if="displayNavBar">
<div class="navigation-bar"
    v-on:click="toggleMenu();">
   <span class="navigation-bar-button left visible"
         v-bind:class="{active: NavBarCtrl.menuActive}">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
@FrankProvost

Comment: where to you initialize your Vue instance?

Comment: @FrankProvost
Thank you very much, i feel stupid now. i had not properly registered the component.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty bad mistake on my behalf:

the above code does work given that you properly register the component.

```
export function setupVM(): Vue {
    const vm = new Vue({
        el: '#navigation-bar',
        components: {
            navigationBar: NavigationBar
        }
    });
    return vm;
}
```